# Save a LatLng array into a database

Tags: android, arrays, string, list

I want to save my track as a list of LatLng in the database. For that, I intend to convert it as a string and then to save in a string field.

For conversion, I have tried to use this code:

```
final ArrayList<LatLng> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
waypoints.addAll(Stream.of(mFavorites)
         .map(i -> coordToLatLng(i.Latitude, i.Longitude))
         .toList());


Toast.makeText(this, waypoints, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and then will save as waypoints.toString to database.

Any better suggestion how to solve my need?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
LatLng latLng;
Double l1=latlng.latitude;
Double l2=latlng.longitude;
String coordl1 = l1.toString();
String coordl2 = l2.toString();
```

1 - convert your lat/long into Double, and separate them;

2 - convert Double to String.

Comment: I need to save all arraylist not just a single location

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store your latitude and longitude in database use this code it will help you :

Simply add LatLng variable and save into database:

```
String s=String.valueOf(latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude)
```

and save  it .

and when want get and use ,use this code:

```
DatabaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper(context);
     String[] latlong = db.getLatLngValue.split(",");
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
               LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

print this latLng variable:

it will help you

Comment: I need to save a full path in same field, not just a location.

Comment: You should store multiple latitude , longitude in database and during show the path draw a path between latitude longitude by google direction api

Comment: and you can also store the LatLng type arraylist in database (convert into string formate) and  show the path ,draw a path between latitude longitude by google direction api .

Comment: I need to save all arraylist not just a single location

Comment: if you can save single location in database so you can save also more value in database,insert the value one by one and when getting value use loop and array list , it would help you

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this approach:**

```
     /**
     * TODO: this is used for set value into waypoint arraylist
     * TODO: but your case you are already having value into one arraylist
     */
    final ArrayList<LatLng> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
    LatLng latlong = new LatLng();
    latlong.setLatitute("13.041695199971244");
    latlong.setLongitude("77.61311285197735");
    waypoints.add(latlong);
    waypoints.add(latlong);
    //////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * TODO: this is approach to convert list data into string array
     * TODO: you can modified your data according to your format.
     */
    String[] mValue = new String[waypoints.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i<waypoints.size(); i++){
       mValue[i] = waypoints.get(i).getLatitute()+","+waypoints.get(i).getLongitude();
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * TODO: final you can see this result and can store into database
     */
    Log.e("value:",""+Arrays.toString(mValue));
```

**LatLng.java**

```
public class LatLng {
        String latitute;
        String longitude;

        public String getLatitute() {
            return latitute;
        }

        public void setLatitute(String latitute) {
            this.latitute = latitute;
        }

        public String getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

> E/value:: [13.041695199971244,77.61311285197735,
>   13.041695199971244,77.61311285197735]

Comment: I try to conver my array into a string that can be saved in SQLite.